# build.sbt ProjectRef : not enough arguments for method apply

Tags: scala, build, sbt, project, external

I am trying to include one external sbt sub project. Please find below build.sbt snippet :-

> lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(
>                     ProjectRef( file("../../ScalaWork/ActorCore"), "ac" )
>                 )

Below is the error that I am getting :-

> [error] C:\git\Test\project\build.scala:49: not enough arguments for
>   method apply: (id: String, base: java.io.File, aggregate: =>
>   Seq[sbt.ProjectReference], dependencies: =>
>   Seq[sbt.ClasspathDep[sbt.ProjectReference]], delegates: =>
>   Seq[sbt.ProjectReference], settings : => Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]],
>   configurations: Seq[sbt.Configuration], auto:
>   sbt.AddSettings)sbt.Project in object Project.

What is the correct syntax to include external sbt project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing for my project

```
lazy val root = Project("myrootproject", file(".")).dependsOn(utility)

lazy val utility = Project("utility", file("libs/utility"))
```

`uility` also happen to be a Scala.js cross-compiled project, so I need to make a reference to them using `LocalProject` after loading in `libs/utility`.

```
lazy val utilityJS = LocalProject("utilityJS")
lazy val utilityJVM = LocalProject("utilityJS")
```